# Consolidate array of dicts by key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an **array of dicts**, with employees listed for each boss:

```
comp = [
    {'employees': ['chris', 'samantha', 'peter'], 'boss': 'Joe'}
    {'employees': ['cristy', 'jebadiah', 'coco'], 'boss': 'Susan'}
    {'employees': ['misty', 'jemima', 'douglas'], 'boss': 'Susan'}
    {'employees': ['arther', 'bily', 'jenkens'], 'boss': 'Susan'}
    {'employees': ['cari', 'sephora', 'betrice'], 'boss': 'Billy'}
]
```

I need to **consolidate** the employees per boss in a new dict like this:

```
comp = [
    {'employees': ['chris', 'samantha', 'peter'], 'boss': 'Joe'}
    {'employees': ['cristy', 'jebadiah', 'coco', 'misty', 'jemima', 'douglas', 'arther', 'bily', 'jenkens'], 'boss': 'Susan'}
    {'employees': ['cari', 'sephora', 'betrice'], 'boss': 'Billy'}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution, but you can use this code:

```
comp = [
    {'employees': ['chris', 'samantha', 'peter'], 'boss': 'Joe'},
    {'employees': ['cristy', 'jebadiah', 'coco'], 'boss': 'Susan'},
    {'employees': ['misty', 'jemima', 'douglas'], 'boss': 'Susan'},
    {'employees': ['arther', 'bily', 'jenkens'], 'boss': 'Susan'},
    {'employees': ['cari', 'sephora', 'betrice'], 'boss': 'Billy'}
]
comp_modified = []

for dct in comp:
    boss_exists = False # Determine if boss was previously added to comp_modified
    for dct2 in comp_modified:
        if dct['boss'] == dct2['boss']:
            boss_exists = True
            for emp in dct['employees']:
                dct2['employees'].append(emp)
    if not boss_exists:
        comp_modified.append({'employees': dct['employees'], 'boss': dct['boss']})
```

This will iterate through `comp` in the outer-most loop using `dct`, then iterate through `comp_modified` in the next loop using `dct2`. In each iteration, if the value of `dct['boss']` has already been added to `comp_modified`, it will append `dct`'s employees to `dct2['employees']`. Otherwise, it will add `dct`'s employees to a new dictionary and add that to `comp_modified`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
>>> index = {}
>>> for i, elem in enumerate(comp[:]):
        current_boss = elem['boss']
        if current_boss in index:
            comp[index[current_boss]]['employees'].extend(elem['employees'])
            del comp[i]
        else:
            index[current_boss] = i
>>> comp
[{'employees': ['chris', 'samantha', 'peter'], 'boss': 'Joe'},
 {'employees': ['cristy',
   'jebadiah',
   'coco',
   'misty',
   'jemima',
   'douglas',
   'arther',
   'bily',
   'jenkens'],
  'boss': 'Susan'},
 {'employees': ['arther', 'bily', 'jenkens'], 'boss': 'Susan'}]
```

Comment: Got index out of range with this approach